# How to identify stripes of different colors

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, identification

how can I identify the presence or absence of regular stripes of different colors, but ranging from very very very very light pink to black inside of a scanned image (bitmap 200x200dpi 24-bit).
Carry a few examples.

Example 1

[image: uno]

Example 2 (the lines are in all the columns except 7 in the second row of the last column)

[image: due]

For now try to identify (using python language) whether or not there is at least 5-10 pixels for the presence of different color from white to each strip, however, does not always work because the scanned image is not of high quality and the strip changes color very similar to color that surrounds it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is some high level Image processing stuff , I am not sure if this can be done in python alone.

Comment: Probably better to ask on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you capable of getting less blurry pictures, or do you have to work with these?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me a [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) in an image to identify discrete regions of certain color range. You can have a look to [cvBlobLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib). Some pre-processing would be required to merge the pixels if there are holes or small variations between neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen. The human visual system is far better than any image processing system, and I don't see anything in the 2nd row of #3. #1 and #5 are also debatable.

You need to find some way to increase the optical quality of your input.

Answer (score 0):

Search for segmentation algorithm ,with a low threshold. 
It should give you good results as the edges are sharp.

Sobel would be a good start ;)